What does the resonance frequency mean in inertia matching
Like Kollmorgen shows in this PDF how you can calculate the resonance frequency of a motor coupled to a load. But with what can I Compare this frequency?
It is clear that a higher resonance frequency is beneficial. But is there a certain value which should be exceeded in order get a stable control?
Can I compare this value to the control frequency of the drive?
I Know the "over the thumb" rules for inertia matching, but I am searching for a way beyond that.
